# Does $f \in B[a,b]$ with only countable many points of discontinuity imply $f ∈ \overline{S[a,b]}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

If $f$ $∈$ $B[a,b]$(the set of bounded functions on[a,b]) has only countable many points of discontinuity, does it follow that $f$ $∈$ $\overline{S[a,b]}$ where $S[a,b]$ denotes the collection of all step functions on $[a,b]$?

supreme norm based.

A function $f$: $[a,b]$ $->$ $\mathbb R$ is called a step function if there are finitely many points a = $t_0$

Comment: How do you define step function? I would think that if $g\in S[a,b],$ then $g([a,b])$ is a finite set. But what is $g^{-1}(\{c\})$ for a $c\in g([a,b])?$ Is $g^{-1}(\{c\})$ a sub-interval of $[a,b],$ or is it an arbitrary subset of $[a,b]?$

Comment: @jflipp: I will add the definition.

Comment: $f(x)=\sin(1/x)$, $0<x\le1$, $f(0)=0$ is not a uniform limit of step functions.

Comment: @DavidMitra: Yes, I thought of this function when I clicked to post it.

Comment: I dont think thomas function (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function) can be written as that way...

Comment: @AnubhaV: ha, that's Reimann function.

Comment: ohhh...sorry...it wont work...bad guess

Comment: @AnubhaV: do some modification that let sin(1/(q-2)) instead of 1/q and it should work on [0,1]

Comment: @AnubhaV: I think the trick here is approching value of function at point of discontinuity should be vibrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another counterexample in the vein of David Mitra's comment.  Take $[a, b] = [0, 1]$ and let $f$ be $1$ on $\left[ \frac{1}{2}, 1 \right]$, $0$ on $\left[ \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{2} \right)$, $1$ on $\left[ \frac{1}{8}, \frac{1}{4} \right)$, 0 on $\left[ \frac{1}{16}, \frac{1}{8} \right)$,etc., and let $f(0) = 1$.  In other words,

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & \text{ if }x = 1, x = 0, \text{ or } \displaystyle \frac{1}{2^{2k + 1}} \leq x < \frac{1}{2^{2k}}, k \in \mathbb{N} \cup \lbrace 0 \rbrace \\
0, & \text{ if } \displaystyle\frac{1}{2^{2k}} \leq x < \frac{1}{2^{2k - 1}}, k \in \mathbb{N} \end{cases}$$

Then no matter what your step function $g$ is, it must have an interval of the form $[0, t_1]$ or $(0, t_1)$ (or the half-open variations) on which it takes a single value $a_1$, and $f$ contains both $0$ and $1$ values here.  By the triangle inequality, clearly $1/2$ is the best possible for $\max{\vert 1 - a_1 \vert, \vert 0 - a_1 \vert}$, which is a lower bound on the supremum norm.

Note that bounded monotone functions are better behaved, and it should be possible, with only countably many discontinuities, to get a good approximation with those.